# How can I group data from one array based on parallel values in another?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am extracting data from a database and storing it in two arrays, one array contains the labels for the data, and the other contains the data. I need to manipulate the arrays in a way so that I have one label for each set of data.

**Arrays right now**

labels - `[Development, Development, Development, Development, Release, Release, Release, Release, ...]`

data - `[DevData1, DevData2, DevData3, DevData4, RelData1, RelData2, RelData3, RelData4, ...]`

I only need only label per set of data, but I want to break the data into segments to correspond with the single labels. There are four label/data pairs because this is data from the last four months. I would just split the array on every 4th element, but some of the months dont have entries. So I need a better way to split the data.

Any ideas would be great. 
Thanks.

Comment: Do the positions in the two arrays always correspond with each other?  Like will position `0` always be ether `Development` and `DevXXX` or can they me mixed up in the two arrays?

Comment: Yes, each label has a corresponding data point in the other array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could combine the separate arrays into a hash without too much effort:

```
a = [:Development, :Development, :Development, :Development, :Release, :Release, :Release, :Release]
b = [:DevData1, :DevData2, :DevData3, :DevData4, :RelData1, :RelData2, :RelData3, :RelData4]
h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [ ] }
a.each_with_index { |e, i| h[e].push(b[i]) }
# h is now {:Development=>[:DevData1, :DevData2, :DevData3, :DevData4], :Release=>[:RelData1, :RelData2, :RelData3, :RelData4]}
```

Just make sure you use `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [ ] }` and not `Hash.new([])` or you'll end up with two hash entries pointing at the same array and that will just make a mess of things.

References:

- [Hash with a default proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000718)
- [`each_with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001511)
- [`push`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000226)

Comment: @Hunter: You might want to become familiar with [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html), [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html), and [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html). There are all kinds of useful things in there.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I am just now starting Ruby, coming from static languages is making the adjustment slow.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store it as a hash?

```
h = {"Development" => [DevData1, DevData2...], "Release" => [RelData1...]}
```

Then you could access "Development" data like this:

```
h["Development"]
# => [DevData1, DevData2...]
```

Comment: The data is already being read in from an XML file into an array, the two arrays are all I have to work with. I can't change how to data is stored.

Answer (score 1):

A not very ruby solution to this would be just to loop through both of the arrays with an iterator and use them as you need them.

Comment: coming from Java, this was my first thought. And as I was typing the solution I stopped due to its non-Ruby-ish-ness